# jQuery / HTML5 select and style parent and all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3.0 to make a nifty looking sidebar. I'm looking to clone the 
current little bit of HTML with jQuery and append it to the page:

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                <div class="list-group">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Upcoming awesome</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Awesome stuff is here</p>                
                </div>
            </a>
```

and JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $appts = $('a.list-group-item > div').contents().andSelf().clone()
            $appts.appendTo('body');

        });
```

Currently, I'm not getting the behavior I hoped, and you can see that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TJbQc/)

I know that HTML4 doesn't allow divs inside of anchor tags, but I'm using Chrome and I still can't get the styling right (notice that bootstrap CSS and bootstrap.js are included in the fiddle).  I've got a couple questions:

1. Why isn't the newly appended jQuery object being styled the same way as the one that's included in the source?
2. Why is jQuery appending the an extra copy of the initial jQuery object?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/QqMD9/

Comment: Not sure what version of jQuery your using but here is something to be mindful of: _"**Note**: This function has been deprecated and is now an alias for [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/), which should be used with **jQuery 1.8** and later."_ per the API docs for [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/).

Comment: @JasonP Yeah, that's it.  I had that initially, but for some reason it wasn't being styled after I appended it.  I'll have to figure out why that's happening in my actual project.

Comment: beacause you are targeting the first div under the anchor element. Try 'a.list-group-item' as your selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your questions in order.

1. The reason the styling is different is because the styling is applied to the `<a>` tag and you are cloning the content *within* the `<a>` tag, not the tag itself.
2. Jquery is appending both the **contents** of the selector and the **selector**, which means you are seeing double.

If you would like to append the styled a tag, the following snippet should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // store a copy of the container 'list-group-item'
    $appts = $('a.list-group-item').clone()
    // append that copy
    $appts.appendTo('body');
});
```